# how can I set a Google Tag Manager event with a value of less that $1?

Tags: google-tag-manager

How can I set a Google Tag Manager event with a value of less that $1?

I'm tracking outbound clicks via a GTM Universal Analytics event tag. Each click of one particular tag is worth 60 cents. I know that the value field requires an integer, so if I enter 1, than that would be $1.

Is there a way to set it up so that it is in cents, so that I could add 60 for the value?

Answer (score 3):

As you pointed out the limitation comes from [Google Analytics which only accepts integers](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#eventValue) as `event value`. So **Google Tag Manager is not going to solve that problem for you**.

What you need to think about is how to solve this problem in Google Analytics. Your options are:

- **Event Label:** use the event level to record value as a string then use another reporting tool (eg API, Google Sheets, Data Studio) to convert those strings to numbers and used those for reporting.

`ga('send', 'event', 'Cat', 'Act', '0.6');`

- **Event Value + Calculated Metrics**: you can assign the event values to a particular goal, set the values `10x` what they are (eg `6` instead of `0.6`) and use a [calculated metric](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6121409?hl=en) to divide those values by `10`.
- **Ecommerce**: use the `price` property of the [ecommerce data](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce) which supports decimals.

Then the rest is just a Google Tag Manager implementation of whichever solution you choose to go for.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a goal in google analytics and set the goal value to 60 cents by typing 0,6 or 0.6 depending on your country/currency and then set the trigger for that goal to your custom event, in this case your click event.

I have tested this way in my analytics account and it seems to work fine.